# Pattern Generator (verilog)

Tags: verilog

I need to program a sequential circuit in Verilog code as a pattern generator which generates, instead of binary counts, your Firstname (space) Lastname (space), character by character. I need to display the pattern sequence for at least two cycles.

[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyM99.png)

This is the sample output:
[sampleoutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hY10h.png)

I know that the issue my program has is in the CoderMod module, but I'm not sure where the issues are.

Thanks for the help!

```
//pattern.v

module TestMod;
   reg CLK;
   wire [0:11] Q;
   wire [6:0] ascii;
   initial begin 
      #1;
      forever begin 
        CLK=0;
        #1;
        CLK=1;
        #1;
      end

   end

   RippleMod my_ripple(CLK, Q);
   CoderMod my_coder(Q, ascii);
   initial #27 $finish;
   initial begin
      $display("Time   CLK   Q                      Name");
      $monitor("%4d    %b    %b    %c  %x  %b", $time, CLK, Q, ascii, ascii, ascii);
   end
endmodule

module CoderMod(Q, ascii); 
   input [0:13]Q;
   output [13:0] ascii;
   assign ascii[0] = "F";
   assign ascii[1] = "i";
   assign ascii[2] = "r";
   assign ascii[3] = "s";
   assign ascii[4] = "t";
   assign ascii[5] = " ";
   assign ascii[6] = "L";
   assign ascii[7] = "a";
   assign ascii[8] = "s";
   assign ascii[9] = "t";
   assign ascii[10] = "n";
   assign ascii[11] = "a";
   assign ascii[12] = "m";
   assign ascii[13] = "e";

   or(ascii[0], Q[13]);
   or(ascii[1], Q[12]);
   or(ascii[2], Q[11]);
   or(ascii[3], Q[10]);
   or(ascii[4], Q[9]);
   or(ascii[5], Q[8]);
   or(ascii[6], Q[7]);
   or(ascii[7], Q[6]);
   or(ascii[8], Q[5]);
   or(ascii[9], Q[4]);
   or(ascii[10], Q[3]);
   or(ascii[11], Q[2]);
   or(ascii[12], Q[1]);
   or(ascii[13], Q[0]);

endmodule

module RippleMod(CLK, Q);
   input CLK;
   output [0:15]Q;
   reg [0:15]Q;
   always @(posedge CLK) begin
      Q[0] <= Q[15]; 
      Q[1] <= Q[0];
      Q[2] <= Q[1];
      Q[3] <= Q[2];
      Q[4] <= Q[3];
      Q[5] <= Q[4];
      Q[6] <= Q[5];
      Q[7] <= Q[6];
      Q[8] <= Q[7];
      Q[9] <= Q[8];
      Q[10] <= Q[9];
      Q[11] <= Q[10];
      Q[12] <= Q[11];
      Q[13] <= Q[12];
      Q[14] <= Q[13];
      Q[15] <= Q[14];
   end

   initial begin 
      Q[0] = 1;
      Q[1] = 0;
      Q[2] = 0;
      Q[3] = 0;
      Q[4] = 0;
      Q[5] = 0;
      Q[6] = 0;
      Q[7] = 0;
      Q[8] = 0;
      Q[9] = 0;
      Q[10] = 0;
      Q[11] = 0;
      Q[12] = 0;
      Q[13] = 0;
      Q[14] = 0;
      Q[15] = 0;
   end
endmodule
```

Comment: Why is the range of `Q` defined as `[0:11]`, `[0:13]`, and `[0:15]`? Why are you assigning an 8-bit value to a single bit of index of `ascii`? And why are you assigning each bit of `ascii` twice (`assign` and `or`)?

Answer (score 0):

There are actually multiple issues with your program. i.e. you declare an ascii arraya as `wire [6:0] ascii;` but later you connect it to the module as `CoderMod my_coder(Q, ascii);` where it is an output port of width 14. You also assig  8-bit characters to a one-bit ascii, like here: `ascii[1] = "i";`

as a hint, you need to declare it as

```
 wire [6:0] ascii [13:0];
```

you shold be able to figure out the rest.